# How can I view different internally hosted websites, set up as virtual hosts?

Tags: dns, webserver, nat, hosts-file, hosting

I have an old machine that I've converted into a web server. I'm wondering what the best way to make the websites viewable on the internal network, without using a proxy.

I experimented with BIND, but I had a lot of trouble getting it going with dynamic DNS. The websites are hosted on different virtual servers, so I can't just go to the IP. The domains are hosted by a 3rd party, and if I try to use them to visit the site, from within the internal network, I am directed to the router configuration page.

Is there a way to set up forwarding on the router so that it treats me as an external visitor and forwards me to the appropriate virtual server?

Unfortunately, it doesn't support NAT loopback, so that is doubtful. Also, the router has a built in DNS server for the internal network. Can I use that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is about to make my head explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have ypu tried adding the site names and internal IP addresses to your hosts file - that works for me with virtual Web sites on a local Linux/Apache development server

Comment: I figured it out. I looked into split DNS and gave BIND another try. Turns out the I just needed to edit resolv.conf, on all of the local computers, to use the local DNS server. Thanks for the input. I can't answer the question for another 3 hours, or hit the up arrow, because I'm new.